# how to convert 01 Jan 2015 20:33:09 in to 01-02-2015 20:33:09 .it returns nil

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdateformatter

I have tried this:

```
NSString *myDateString = @"29 Feb 2016 20:33:09";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];

NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];

NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *myDateString = @"29 Feb 2016 20:33:09";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your required Format,Use this:-

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: @huy nghia so please tell what is the right format ?

Comment: It is the right format,Its been 3 yrs while m using it..........and Thanks for negative vote.

Comment: thanx ayan you are right but some foolish person love to make negative marking.

Comment: @AnuragSharma If I fail I'm sorry!
but you shouldn't say that 
firstly MM: return 1~12 (0 padded Month)
second hh: use only for 1~12 (0 padded Hour (12hr)

Comment: @AyanKhan I'm sorry for down vote after you reply I try cancel but I can't

Answer (score 0):

Your convert date `nil` because you didn't use right dateFormat
try :

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

more [infomation](https://tahabebek.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/)

Answer (score 0):

NSString *myDateString = @"29 Feb 2016 20:33:09";

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSString *myDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString *myDateString = @"29 Feb 2016 20:33:09";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];

//here i get correct date ok But

NSLog(@"%@", myDate);

NSString *ss=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myDate] ;

NSArray *components = [ss componentsSeparatedByString: @"+"];

NSString *StartnewDateString = [components objectAtIndex:0];

//Here time is changed of StartnewDateString